# Problems getting a sticky footer working

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky

I have a site I'm currently working on which requires a sticky footer as some of the pages content is smaller then the rest.

[My Website](http://dirtythreewines.com.au/the-vineyard/)

I have tried many resources/tutorials trying to get a sticky footer working.

[Tutorial Followed](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

I have attempted to implement this tutorial and below is my code which goes with it. I'm hoping someone

Could anybody possibly suggest CSS changes to my code to implement this feature.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header-wrap">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="home-header"></div>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-wrap">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#footer-wrap
{
    background: url("images/footer.jpg") repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;
    color: rgb(117, 139, 141);
    height: 462px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#header-wrap
{
    clear: both;
    min-height: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: -462px; 
}
#header-wrap:after
{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:462px;
}
```

Not working for me. Need Help!

Also 'push' is not in use. Use it maybe?

EDIT

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0px
}

html
{
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper
{
    min-height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #footer-wrap
    {
        height: 462px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin:0px;
      background: #eee;
        margin-bottom: -462px; 
    }

    #wrapper
    {
        min-height: auto !important;
        min-height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-bottom: -462px;
    }
    #wrapper:after
    {
        content:"";
        display:block;
        height:462px;
    }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header-wrap">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="home-header"></div>
    <div id="page-wrap"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer-wrap">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry yes. I just added that.

Comment: then i think the problem is that your footer is inside of your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by css trick

**css**

```
body, html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}

.header{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#066;
}

.footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#006;
    width:100%;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div style=" text-align:center; padding-top:25px;">
         Place you content here as much as you like
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

working [js Fiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/p3vTY/)

Answer (score 0):

This works.

**CSS**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body, #wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.header-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -462px; 
}
.header-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
#footer-wrap, .header-wrap:after {
  height: 462px; 
}
#footer-wrap {
  background: orange;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrap">
        <div id="header">#header</div>
        <div id="home-header">#home-header</div>
    </div>

    <footer id="footer-wrap">
      #footer-wrap
    </footer>
</div>
```